ClickHouse: How to select part of json by paths?
Given an arbitrary JSON in ClickHouse:
{
  "id": 123,
  "name": "John",
  "metadata": {
    "foo": "bar",
    "nums": [1, 2, 3]
  }
}

And an arbitrary list of paths: ['id', 'metadata.nums', 'not.existing'] (or any similar format)
Is there any way to select json's part based on specified paths?
For paths specified above I expect this result:
{
  "id": 123,
  "metadata": {
    "nums": [1, 2, 3]
  }
}

I have considered approaches with built-in functions (like JSON_VALUE with JsonPath or JSONExtractKeysAndValuesRaw), but each of them returns either values without keys or only value by one path

There are likely multiple ways to parse and access this JSON data using ClickHouse - there are quite a few different functions for handling JSON. Here's one example that a String column to store the JSON Tuple data, and then uses JSONExtractString to parse that string when needed:
// Create the table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS json_sample
(
    `id` UInt32,
    `name` String,
    `metadata` String
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
ORDER BY id;

// Insert the data from your raw JSON data
INSERT INTO json_sample FROM file('./myJSON.json', 'JSONEachRow');
// Select the data using JSONExtractString
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    JSONExtractString(metadata, 'foo'),
    JSONExtractString(metadata, 'nums')
FROM json_sample;

Query id: ba698471-e5d4-4bcb-8755-7a379145a5f4

┌──id─┬─name─┬─JSONExtractString(metadata, 'foo')─┬─JSONExtractString(metadata, 'nums')─┐
│ 123 │ John │ bar                                │ [1,2,3]                             │
└─────┴──────┴────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────┘


The problem is that I have schemeless arbitrary jsons and I want to filter them all so that only the fields passed in path array remain:
paths = ['a.b', 'c']
jsons = [{"a": {"b": 1}, "d": 2}, {"a": 1, "c": 2}]
result = [{"a": {"b": 1}}, {"c": 2}]
